# IF Function has stopped working

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a workbook that has check boxes assigned to cells to declare true or false assigning a score for each true. The function I have in place reads =IF(C41=TRUE,"4",IF(E41=TRUE,"3",IF(G41=TRUE,"2",IF(I41=TRUE,"1","0"))))
This function was working then out of the blue stopped when I put in a sum formula to compile the results on a different sheet. Any ideas why this may be happening?

Comment: I doubt that the `if` function has stopped working ... it simply behaves differently from what you thought ... review each section of the formula ... start at the innermost `if` .... put each `if` statement in a separate cell

Comment: is the `IF` formula not giving you output, or is it the `SUM` formula giving you -0-? Your `IF` formula numbers are in quotes meaning the actual output of the formula would be text which would add to -0-.

Comment: jsotola- I tried separating the function out to a single logic test and that still didn't work. Prior to this if I selected a checkbox it would give the paired celled a true value thus returning a value in the box with the logic function. Now it still gives the true value but nothing happens in the cell with the logic function.

Comment: gns100- the IF formula is not giving an output. I established a work around for the sum function by using =SUM(sheet!b1*1,sheet!b2*1...). I entered the sum formula and checked it by selecting boxes and it worked. Went to the next sheet to do the same thing, Excel froze for a second and then nothing has worked on the IF sense then.

Answer (score 1):

As @JohnSUN mentioned - your if formula is returning text, not a number.
The image below is showing your formula.

- `B38` is returning 4 as cell `C41` contains `TRUE`
- `B38` is naturally left aligned indicating the number is being treated as text.
- The sum of `B38` is equal to 0 as it contains text.

[image]

At the bottom of the image I've adjusted your formula.

- I've removed `=TRUE` as it's not needed.  The `IF` function wants to see if the value in `C41` is TRUE - as it only contains TRUE/FALSE there's no need to check if it's TRUE/FALSE just pass that value straight in. (Hope I explained that clearly).
- I've removed the quotes from around the numbers so they're treated as numbers and not text.
- The `SUM` function now recognises the number and works.

So the formula should be `=IF(C41,4,IF(E41,3,IF(G41,2,IF(I41,1,0))))`,
or if you really want it could be `=IF(C41=TRUE,4,IF(E41=TRUE,3,IF(G41=TRUE,2,IF(I41=TRUE,1,0))))`